# Time Complexity of checking whether a string is present in a HashSet Java

Tags: java, string, hashmap, hashset

In a nutshell, I am confused whether the time complexity of checking whether a String exists in a HashSet is O(1) or O(m), m being the length of the longest string being checked.

I understand that the bucket in which the string is going to be placed is determined by the `hashCode()` method of the string modulo the size of the HashSet. So this means that in order to find out if a string exists in a HashSet, the hashCode needs to be calculated.

In the `hashCode` method of the `String` class, I can see that you have to iterate over the entire string to calculate this value. But I also see that there is an option of caching this value.

This is where I am confused. Is the hashcode of a String cached during the creation of a String? Or is it cached when we explicitly call the `hashcode` method? Does implicit call to the `hashCode` method (as in the case of checking whether the String exists in a Set) also cache the value?

What would be the time complexity of the very first existence check for a String in HashSet?

Thank you.

EDIT: Since it seems I did not explain what I am asking well enough:
I am not talking about time complexity if chaining occurs (which would happen if there is hash collisions) / or when the Hash Set is resized. Assume for now that there are no collisions in the Hash Set. Hence size of every bucket is at max 1. In this case, if I am checking if a String is present in the Hash Set, will it take O(1) time, or O(m) time (because the string can have O(m) characters in the worst case and calculating hash code requires traversal of the entire string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the String you’re checking is a *new* String, its hashCode must be calculated to find its bucket, so that would be O(m) for the hashCode calculation and O(1) for the existence check, so O(m).

If the String object already exists in the Set (or its hashCode has otherwise been calculated), checking it is O(1), because its hashCode is cached.

Comment: Thank you. So is this understanding correct: 
1) hashcode of a string is not calculated/cached when the string is first created (either using `new` operator or using String lilterals).
2) `String test = "I am a new string"; hashSet.contains(test); hashSet.contains(test); `
The first `contains()` check will take O(m) time, the second `contains()` check will take O(1) time. Because now the hascode of test has been cached?

Comment: @rgbk21 Yes. It's [lazily initialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) on first call to `hashCode()`. All operations with a HashSet require the hashCode.

Answer (score 0):

The time to calculate a given hashCode is dependent on the algorithm and whether it needs to be calculated per call.  An `Integer` makes no calculations as the hashCode is the `int` value.  A String would be `O(n)` where `n` is the number of characters.

Here is the hashCode algorithm for `Latin1` strings.

```
public static int hashCode(byte[] value) {
        int h = 0;
        for (byte v : value) {
            h = 31 * h + (v & 0xff);
        }
        return h;
    }
```

However, the hashCode for a String is only calculated once since the String is immutable. So hashCode calls to a String would return the cached value.